# Unable to access cookie set on same page after if statement

Tags: php, html, cookies, localhost

I set a cookie inside php tag on top of the page:

```
   $cookie_name = "true";
   $cookie_value = "bla";
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, "/");
   echo $cookie_name;   // first

   if(isset($_COOKIE["true"]))
   echo $cookie_name;   // second
```

First echo seems to work fine but I can't echo the second one. It seems as if the if statement is not equaling to true. Can somebody clarify what is going on? Can there be a syntax error? I am new to cookies and trying this on localhost with url api.app.localhost.

Edit#1: Infact replacing first with echo $_COOKIE["true"] also gives blank output. Is syntax wrong?

Comment: I suggest that `$_COOKIE` global variable has cookies that you received with the request, and your new cookie doesn't stored there, but prepared to be send via response headers from the server. And with next request, your server will receive this cookie.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by next request?

Comment: just clear the cookies in browser, reload a page, first time you'll see just a cookie name, and browser will received a new cookie via headers. Reload page again, and, probably, you'll see cookie name twice, because now browser sent you a cookie, which was set with previous request.

Comment: nothing of this sort is happening. I still get the same results after deleting cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of setcookie indicates the expire time

try this:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600); // this expires in 1 hour
```